# Where should I use get_option in a plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, options

I am working on creating a plugin to help me with future development projects. I want to make sure what I am using best practices when I write it. My question is about the use of get_option in my plugin.

I have setup an options page for the plugin and have set a couple options there. Is it better to check the option on the add_action step or with the function that is being added. I have written up a short example to help illustrate my question. Thanks!

```
if ( get_option('my_option[option_1]') ==='1' ) {
  add_action('init', 'my_action')
}
```

or

```
add_action('init', 'my_action');
function my_action() {
  if ( get_option('my_option[option_1]') ==='1' ) {
    //do stuff here
  }
```

My thoughts are that if I check get_option first then I can set it as a var in my plugin and then just check the var anytime I need it. But as I said I am new to plugin development so I don't fully understand the best way to use get_option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both ways are almost equal, the first will be slightly faster, because the callback is called only if the check equals to `TRUE`.

Note you cannot test an option like this, unless the option name is really `'my_option[option_1]'`. What you probably want is:

```
if ( $test = get_option('my_option') and 1 === $test['option_1'] )
    add_action();
```

An extended example:

```
$my_options = get_option('my_option');

if ( 1 === $my_options['test_1'] )
    add_action( 'init', 'my_init' );

if ( 1 === $my_options['test_2'] )
    add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_shutdown' );

// clean up
unset( $my_options );
```